# How to prove that this series converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Prove that
$$ \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{\log (n+1)-\log n}{(\log n)^2}$$
converges.

Comment: I try use cauchy, but I can't conclude

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\log(n+1) - \log(n) = \log\left( 1 + 1/n \right) \sim_{\infty} \frac{1}{n}$$

Next, use integral test.

Comment: How did you make the last step? Not criticizing, just curious.

Comment: @Nitin: $\log(1+ u)$ behaves just like $u$ as $u \to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

By the mean value theorem,
$$\log(n+1) - \log(n) < \sup_{c \in (n,n+1)} \frac{1}{c} = \frac{1}{n}$$
so we have
$$ \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{\log (n+1)-\log n}{(\log n)^2} < \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(\log n)^2}.$$
Showing the latter series converges by the integral test is easy.

Answer (score 1):

1. Rewrite
   $$
   \frac{\ln(n+1)-\ln(n)}{\ln(n)\cdot\ln(n)}=\frac{\ln(n+1)-\ln(n)}{\ln(n)\cdot\ln(n+1)}\cdot\frac{\ln(n+1)}{\ln(n)}.
   $$
2. Estimate the second factor for $n\ge 2$
   $$
   1\le\frac{\ln(n+1)}{\ln(n)}\le 2.
   $$
   (Indeed, $\ln(n+1)\le 2\ln(n)=\ln(n^2)$ since $n+1\le n^2$ in the range).
3. The first factor is telescopic
   $$
   \frac{\ln(n+1)-\ln(n)}{\ln(n)\cdot\ln(n+1)}=
   \frac{1}{\ln(n)}-\frac{1}{\ln(n+1)}.
   $$
4. Combine to conclude convergence.